# javascript auto complete function

Tags: javascript

Hello i have the following code with problems, i'm trying to make it when you click on the output to insert it into the input field. Can you help me please, been trying for hours without any luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var input = $('#CompanyName');
var output = $('#output');
var timer;

input.on('keyup', function() {
    delaySearch(this.value); 
});

function delaySearch(keywords) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        performSearch(keywords);
    }, 1000);
}
function performSearch(keywords) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/print/order/search",
      data: { query: keywords },
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      async: true,
      success: function(data) {
        for(var key in data) {
          output.append('<li onclick="fill('+ data[key].ClientName +')">' + data[key].ClientName) + '</li>';
        }
      }
  });
}
function fill(thisValue) {
  input.val(thisValue);
  clearTimeout(timer);
}
</script>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="CompanyName">Firma</label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="CompanyName" onblur="fill();" name="CompanyName" type="text" placeholder="Firma" class="form-control input-md">
  <ul id="output"></ul>
  <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
</div>


Uncaught ReferenceError: somevalue is not defined
```

Update:
After adding jquery ready function i noticed some errors around and fixed them here is an update on the code

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="CompanyName">Firma</label>
          <div class="col-md-5">
          <input id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" type="text" placeholder="Firma" class="form-control input-md">
          <ul id="output"><li onclick="fill(Ionut)">Ionut</li></ul>
          <span class="help-block">Nume Firma</span>
          </div>
        </div> 



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $('#CompanyName');
  var output = $('#output');
  var timer;

  input.on('keyup', function() {
      delaySearch(this.value); 
  });

  function delaySearch(keywords) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
          performSearch(keywords);
      }, 1000);
  }
  function fill(thisValue) {
    input.val(thisValue);
  }
  function performSearch(keywords) {

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/print/order/search",
        data: { query: keywords },
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
          for(var key in data) {
            output.append('<li onclick="fill(' + data[key].ClientName + ')">' + data[key].ClientName) + '</li>';
          }
        }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

onclick the error persists

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fill is not defined
```

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you want to click the text about the input field and have it be put in the input field?

Comment: yes.. been busting my head all day long .. and didn't quite understand how to do this part

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting

Comment: are the <li> elements being added after the data is being loaded?

Comment: yes the js is placed at the bottom of the html file i only posted here the required data didn't want to add extra code for nothing. i've posted only the input part where i use the js code since the form contains about 20 inputs.. would be a mess :-)

Comment: When I add <ul id="output"><li onclick="fill('Sean')">Sean</li></ul> and click on it, the name is added to the input.

Comment: yes but you have 'Sean' and i have Sean can't manage to add the '' to the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

realseanp is onto the correct answer. I'll try to explain it a little better for you. When a browser starts processing and rendering a page, it loads top down. So your javascript scripts are being ran and evaluated before the DOM is created.

So your jquery selectors: `var input = $('#CompanyName');` if you were to inspect them are going to be an empty array. They cannot find the #CompanyName element because it has not yet been rendered.

If you use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function, then you can be assured that your code will not run until the dom is finished rendering, and therefore will find the elements as you intend them to. So in the end, your code will need to change to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Put your code in here.
    //It will then fire once the dom is ready.
});
```

UPDATE:

Additionally, with your update. I'm noticing that the error is that 'fill' is not defined. fill being your onclick method. You have your js script evaluating after the dom is rendered. So at the time that the dom is rendered, and the tag with the onclick is rendered, no fill method yet exists. Two solutions:

1. Move the script above the dom, and place a `var fill;` outside of the `$(document).ready` so essentially this:

   var fill;
      $(document.ready(function(){
          //your code
      });
2. Don't use the onclick dom attribute, and instead use jquery to bind the event. So change
    Ionut

to this:

```
  <ul id="output"><li>Ionut</li></ul>
```

and inside the document.ready, add:

```
 $('#output li').click(function(e) {
     fill(/*your value/*)
 });
```

Comment: yes the solution was with click that's why it didn't work. thank you everyone for taking time to read my post and help me find a solution :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your script below your HTML. That or wrap it in the jQuery Document ready function. And make sure you have jQuery loaded on the page, before your script